# java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132389600bytes) bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to retrieve images from a web server into my app. However, when I viewed the image in the app, the app crashes.

Here's the code:

```java
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String file_url=null;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        toggleProgress();

    }
    public boolean dir_exists(String dir_path)
    {
        boolean ret = false;
        File dir = new File(dir_path);
        if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
            ret = true;
        return ret;
    }
    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            String dir_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + getResources().getString(R.string.DownloadFolder);

            if (!dir_exists(dir_path)){
                File directory = new File(dir_path);
                if(directory.mkdirs()){
                    Log.v("dir","is created 1");
                }else{
                    Log.v("dir","not created 1");

                }
                if(directory.mkdir()){
                    Log.v("dir","is created 2");
                }else{
                    Log.v("dir","not created 2");

                }
            }else{
                Log.v("dir","is exist");
            }

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dir_path+title.toString().replace("/","_")+"."+extension);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();


            output.close();
            input.close();
            this.file_url = dir_path + title.toString().replace("/", "_") + "." + extension;
            if (blurvalue!=0){
                File file =  new File(this.file_url);
                Log.v("BASSAM","NEW FILE");

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Log.v("BASSAM","OPTIONS");

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
                Log.v("BASSAM","bitmap");

                bitmap = bitmapBlur;
                Log.v("BASSAM","fastblur");

                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.file_url);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("BASSAM",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132389600bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:110)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: see [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Comment: And please format lengthy error messages as code, so that the line breaks don't get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

It wil be good aproach adjusting image size before showing, according to the display size of the device. Try this:

```
//->reduce size of bitmap for displaying on imageView
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
float RealWidth = bmp.getWidth();
float RealHeight = bmp.getHeight();
int NewWidth, NewHeight;
if (imageView.getWidth() > imageView.getHeight()) {
    NewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
    NewHeight = (int) ((RealHeight * NewWidth) / RealWidth);
} else {
    NewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
    NewWidth = (int) ((RealWidth * NewHeight) / RealHeight);
}
bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, NewWidth, NewHeight, false);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you decode your picture file into memory, you'd better read the size of the picture and compare it to the size of your phone, zoom out and finally decode it.

Check out the link in the comment.